# How do I traversing an array in html-webpack-plugin while using template

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

For example, there are lot's of js file output.

1.js
2.js
3.js
....

Target html:

```
<script src="1.js"></script>
<script src="2.js"></script>
<script src="3.js"></script>
```

a fragment of code for describe (use .html template).

```
for (let item of <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.js %>) {
  <script src="<%= item %>"></script>
}
```